# Pause Android LogCat output

Tags: logging

How can I get a wider LogCat output than the one from the terminal window? I also want to be able to pause the output so I can actually read something.

My OS is Windows 7 X64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Windows

Its easier, what you can do is this, from the *cmd* window, `adb logcat > my_logcat.txt` and just let it run, now, you can pause, resume the scrolling, in that *cmd* window, same keystrokes for Linux terminal, IIRC, now launch an editor and open the file 'my_logcat.txt' and there the results will show, had there not being a pause/resume in the cmd window, the file will get updated, such as using '[notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)', '[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)' or similar, the in-built Windows's version of Notepad would do very little justice.

## Linux

From a Linux terminal under a GUI such as KDE/Gnome, using the two utilities combined, found on most distributions, *[multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/)*, which is like a `tail` unix utility, only more powerful!

```
adb logcat # want to see the logcat on the screen
```

Using Ctrl+S to suspend, then Ctrl+Q to resume the display, and simply mouse scroll the terminal to back-track seeing the logcat output.

The other way is this...

```
adb logcat > my_logcat.txt 2>&1 & 
multitail my_logcat.txt
```

The first line above creates a background process by using the `&` at the end of the command, redirecting any errors to `/dev/null` hence `2>&1`.

As the process is forked into the background, using `multitail` can perform, scroll-back on the logcat.

Comment: I forgot the > in the instruction below lol. Thank you for the detailed solution for both linux and windows ;) +1

Answer (score 4):

If you are using LogCat viewer in Eclipse you can click the "Scroll Lock" button to prevent it from automatically scrolling down.

[image: Eclipse LogCat viewer]

It is the icon on the top right in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what logcat does so I can only guess you should use it the same way you do with any other command that spews out text.

Redirect the output to a file you can read in an editor or view with `less`

```
$>logcat [<option>] [<filter-spec>] > /path/to/a/file-to-open-in-an-editor
```

Comment: Well, I can't get this working. For some reason everything on my C drive, including the desktop, is read-only for the terminal window... see: http://piclair.com/data/2to2f.jpg

Isn't there a simple application that monitors logcat output and has the ability to pauze the output? That would make things a lot easier